# Increasing width of a curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a Chi-square curve using the following code :

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 30)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 8))
```

I would like to increase the thickness of the curve. I tried to add

```
geom_line(size=2)
```

to the instructions but it results in an error:

```
Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

What is the proper way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `size` argument within the `stat_function` call:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 30)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 8), size=2)
```